# Dismissing the image picker from the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method now impossible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

This seems like a simple question and I've seen similar ones answered but the answers just don't work (at least anymore).  I have the following code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    {imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;}
    imagePicker.delegate=self;

    NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear");
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        NSLog (@"Modal Window Displayed.");}
```

This allows the user to select an image from the image library, which works. Once that image is picked, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo gets called which has this code at the top of it:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    NSLog(@"Image Is Picked");
    [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

As you can see, I've tried several different ways found here on StackOverflow to get this to work.  They all get ignored.  No errors, just nothing happens; the picker view never goes away.  What gives?  I'm using xCode 7.2.1.

I have a similar place in my code where I present another modal view and also can't get rid of it.

Comment: did you try  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ??

Comment: Yes.  That was in there at one time (it feels like I've tried EVERYTHING).  I just put that in too and get the same result.  Nothing.

Comment: Note that the rest of the code in didFinishPickingmedia runs fine.  The view just doesn't go away.

Comment: I've also tried adding the image picker as a property of the view controller, synthesizing it, then asking that to dismiss itself.  No luck.

Comment: can you please share the example project.

Comment: I've found...more about the problem.  If I remove the rest of my code in my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, MOST of the techniques I tried to dismiss the view suddenly work!  The rest of the code transfers the chosen image to a processing/OCR server and then displays the results of the OCR on another modal window (which I was having trouble dismissing also).  I found that no matter what I do, this method waits until the END of it's execution to actually dismiss the picker.  WHY?  Is there a way to make it dismiss it immediately?

Comment: The problem is that the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method doesn't actually dismiss the other view until it is DONE with it's execution (even if what's running in that method takes almost a minute!).  By the time that method was done, I had already presented another viewcontroller modally.  I guess I answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method doesn't actually dismiss the other view until it is DONE with it's execution (even if what's running in that method takes almost a minute!).  By the time that method was done, I had already presented another viewcontroller modally.  Almost all of the techniques I'd been trying all along actually still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you present with `presentViewController` instead of `presentModalViewController`:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated: YES];
```

then

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

should work - perhaps the combination of different functions you are calling all at once is confusing things.

If this doesn't work, perhaps try presenting it with a slight delay with `dispatch_after` - it could be that presenting it within `viewDidAppear` is causing the issue:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me perfectly. Hope it helps.
in class.h

```
@interface class : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}
```

in class.m when `getPhoto` called, PickerViewController presented.

```
- (IBAction)getPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;     
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker2 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker2 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Globally declare your imagePicker like below

```
@implementation ViewController{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
}
```

Display your image picker declared globally

```
- (IBAction)chooosePic:(id)sender {   
    imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;     {imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;}
    imagePicker.delegate=self;
    NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear");
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    NSLog (@"Modal Window Displayed.");
}
```

didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method update as below:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Will Work